# Lyx hierarchical lists

Tags: lists, lyx

there. I am trying to build a list like this in LyX, but I CANNOT. I need to write something after 1.

[image]

Any idea to do this in LyX? I can do it in LaTeX using code.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lyx nested enumerate creation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192215/lyx-nested-enumerate-creation)

Answer (score 4):

There may be a better of doing this, as it is sort of clumsy:

1. Start an enumerated list, by selecting Enumerate from the drop down menu.
2. Add an empty ERT-box at the start of the item, move the cursor outside it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This starts a sublist, which is numbered with letters.
4. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> starts a new item in the sublist, to make this a new item on the main list, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time.

As you state, there has to be something in the items of the mainlist before the sublist, but an empty ERT is sufficient.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Also you can just hit `Enter` twice to go back to the main list.

Comment: @DaijiangLi Ah, yes, that was a little bit easier. (I don't really use LyX.) Please consider accepting (and/or upvoting) my answer if it solved your problem, that marks the question as solved and awards some reputation points to both me and yourself.