# How can I create an enumerated list nested inside another enumerated list, without any initial text in the first level?

Tags: lyx, lists, nesting

I tried to create the following in LyX. But it does not give what I want.

```
1 (a) text
      OR
  (b) text

2 (a) (i) text
      (ii) text
     OR
  (b) text
```

LyX does allow only to produce as shown below

```
1 Text
  (a) text
```

[image]

The working code in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show a minimal (non)working example?

Comment: @bernard I have added the image from LyX

Comment: I meant the LaTeX code (a minimal example).

Comment: @Bernard I have added the working latex code. It does not come in LyX.

Comment: But the image does not correspond to you code: in your code there's no `Text` right after the first item. Another question isn't clear to me: what is the status of the `OR` conjunction in your specifications? I mean, e.g. should the first OR be at the first level enumeration or at the second level?

Comment: LyX image is non-working image. I am unable to produce 1. (a) in lyx. This is my problem.

Comment: I have problem with LyX. It does not allow me to nest enumerate items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to trick LyX a bit to do this, as it doesn't appear to allow you to add a new list item if the previous one is empty. A workaround is to add an empty ERT box in the first list item, then outside the ERT hit enter followed by tab to create the sublist.

Here is how it appears in LyX and PDF with the default document settings. Those empty boxes are ERTs added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble across this thread and don't know how to make a nested enumerated list at all. You have to click on this symbol, which is about in the middle of Lyx's toolbar.
[image]