# Text between items of enumerate without using enumitem

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

Hello I want to do an explanation between the items of a enumerate environment, I found this:

```
\newcounter{saveenumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enumeratext}[1]{%
\setcounter{saveenumerate}{\value{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}
\end{enumerate}
#1
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\value{saveenumerate}}%
}
\makeatother
```

And I thought it work, but the problem is that if I change the numbers of enumerate with letters, it fails, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcounter{saveenumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enumeratext}[1]{%
\setcounter{saveenumerate}{\value{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}
\end{enumerate}
#1
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\value{saveenumerate}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A list:
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item number 1
\item things note usefull,
\item hello mom, I am famous;
\enumeratext{Some intertext}
\item not really, so sad.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Any idea would help, I know the use of [resume] in enumitem, but using that package I don't know how to change the numbers for letters. Thanks.

Comment: Like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401427/11604) or  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482710/11604)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying assumption is that you insist on using `enumerate` rather than `enumitem`. There are valid reasons for that, but the inability of `enumitem` to provide lists that are numbered by roman numerals is not one of them because `enumitem` can do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
A list:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
  \item number 1
 \item things note useful,
 \item hello mom, I am famous;
\end{enumerate} 
Some intertext
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
 \item not really, so sad.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, we assume that there is such another reason like that you did everything else with `enumerate` or some incompatibility. Then you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcounter{saveenumerate}
\makeatletter
\def\enumerate{%
  \xdef\@last@enumerate@arg{none}%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >3 \@toodeep\else
      \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
      \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}\fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\@@enum@}{\@enum@}}
\def\@@enum@[#1]{%
  \xdef\@last@enumerate@arg{#1}%
  \@enLab{}\let\@enThe\@enQmark
  \@enloop#1\@enum@
  \ifx\@enThe\@enQmark\@warning{The counter will not be printed.%
   ^^J\space\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces The label is: \the\@enLab}\fi
  \expandafter\edef\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname{\the\@enLab}%
  \expandafter\let\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname\@enThe
  \csname c@\@enumctr\endcsname7
  \expandafter\settowidth
            \csname leftmargin\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
            {\the\@enLab\hspace{\labelsep}}%
  \@enum@}
\newcommand{\enumeratext}[1]{%
\setcounter{saveenumerate}{\value{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}
\end{enumerate}
#1
\def\@none{none}
\ifx\@last@enumerate@arg\@none%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{enumerate}}%
\else
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{enumerate}[\@last@enumerate@arg]}%
\fi
\temp%
\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\value{saveenumerate}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A list:
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item number 1
\item things note useful,
\item hello mom, I am famous;
\enumeratext{Some intertext}
\item not really, so sad.

\end{enumerate}

A list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item number 1
\item things note useful,
\item hello mom, I am famous;
\enumeratext{Some intertext}
\item not really, so sad.

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

@DavidCarlisle: this may be bad, but is certainly not as bad as BREXIT.